# Instance variable nil when in certain location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, instance-variables

I'm trying to use the value of a controller instance variable in a view. The value of the variable will change depending on the value of a session variable. I was testing it out and I noticed that if I set the variable in a specific location it always comes up as nil.

I'm using Devise for authentication and every time I set the variable after the last Devise function it comes up as nil. But when I place it any where else it shows up fine. I just think that's weird and would like to know why it happens. Everything else works fine except for me setting the instance variable which is completely separate from Devise authentication.

@prop is the variable I'm trying to set up. If I set it like this, when I try to get to references the value in the view it shows up as nil

```
def new
self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)      
clean_up_passwords(resource)        
yield resource if block_given?      
respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
@prop = "test value"
end
```

But when I set it like this or any other line before the `respond_with` I get the correct value in the view.

```
def new
@prop = "test value"
self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)      
clean_up_passwords(resource)        
yield resource if block_given?      
respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
end
```

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`respond_with` is triggering the responder and it makes view rendered. As you put another variable after the `respond_with`, the view won't recognize it.

Comment: Oh, so `respond_with` is what triggers the rendering of the view. That makes total sense now why anything set afterward wouldn't appear. I kind of figured something like that was the cause, but as I'm new to Rails I wanted to be sure what the exact cause was.
Thanx so much for you explanation.